# php mysqli generate list items from each line in database table

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following inside a table in my database which is named "duties"

```
Progressing of new Engineering & Technical enquiries from client
Expediting jobs
Resolving any client's requests
Quote processing
Communicating and liaising between client and Team Leader
Progressing of new repair enquiries
Attend meetings with clients and generating enquiries
Build relationships and obtain new orders from clients
Liaising with customer planners to organise offshore trips
Assisting in the workshop during busy periods
```

It's inputted into the database via a Textarea and each is a new line.

When outputting the database cell it shows as one single line. But if I echo it using `nl2br` it adds `<br>` to the code so it shows as a list.

```
$result2 = $con->query('SELECT * FROM role WHERE id = "'.$row['role'].'"');
while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<p>".nl2br($row2['duties'])."</p>";
}
```

Is there a way to change it so that it echos each line instead of `<br>` it will be actual list items like the following?

```
<li>Progressing of new Engineering & Technical enquiries from client</li>
<li>Expediting jobs</li>
<li>Resolving any client's requests</li>
<li>Quote processing</li>
<li>Communicating and liaising between client and Team Leader</li>
<li>Progressing of new repair enquiries</li>
<li>Attend meetings with clients and generating enquiries</li>
<li>Build relationships and obtain new orders from clients</li>
<li>Liaising with customer planners to organise offshore trips</li>
<li>Assisting in the workshop during busy periods</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `while` loop, replace:

```
echo "<p>".nl2br($row2['duties'])."</p>";
```

with

```
$withLineBreaks = nl2br($row2['duties']) ;
echo "<li>" . str_replace ( "<br/>", "</li><li>" , mixed $withLineBreaks) . "</li>";
```

(If you have a trailing line-break at the end of your data, you'll end up with an excess/empty `<li></li>` at the end - so you might need to trim that off first).

Of course, you could just replace those line breaks directly rather than using `nl2br` at all, if you have the right regex.  Not in a position to test this, but think this should get any of the usual line-break formats:

```
echo "<li>" . preg_replace("#[\n\r]{1,2}#","</li><li>", $row2['duties']) . "</li>";
```

Comment: This has just wrapped the entire list with a `<li>` tag and closes it at the end. each `<br>` is still present

Comment: @DonaldSutherland Sorry, if you're getting `<br>` tags, not `<br/>`, then update the replace to replace `<br>` instead of `<br/>`.  But the regex option will be better (assuming it's the right regex for your line-ending format).